# CNN archicture with keras

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I am working with a binary classification problem with Python (keras).

my CNN network architecture is given below:

```
    def CNN():
      model = Sequential()
      model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(1, 3), activation='elu', padding='valid', input_size=(20,10, 1)))
      model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(1, 3), activation='elu', padding='valid'))
      model.add(Conv2D(16, kernel_size=(1, 3), activation='elu', padding='valid'))

      model.add(Flatten())
      model.add(Dense(512, activation='elu'))
      model.add(Dense(512, activation='sigmoid'))
```

Now I am trying to describe my CNN architecture in a table:
I have one dimensional dataset with 200 column 200k number of rows.

Batch Size = 64

CNN 1 - channel 64
CNN 2 - channel 32
CNN 3 - channel 16

FC1 - 500 units
FC2 - 1 Unit

Here I am trying to describe the architecture in a table (problem in this section)

## --             CNN1     --       CNN2 --          CNN3   --   FC1 --  FC2

Input_Shape--  64* 64 * 200 * 1 -- 32* 64 * 200 * 1 -- 16* 64 * 200 * 1 -- 16*64*200*1*500 - 16*64*200*1*500

Output_Shape -- 32* 64 * 200 * 1 - 16* 64 * 200 * 1 - 16* 64 * 200 * 1 - 16*64*200*1*500 -- 1

I am heaving trouble to define the correct input output shape of my network, seeking some help. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The input shape for a standard CNN for image classification in Keras is as follows :

```
input_shape = ( batch_size , height , width , num_channels )
```

The 1st `Conv2D` layer will have an input shape of :

```
img_height = 20
img_width = 10
num_channels = 1

model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(1, 3), activation='elu', padding='valid', 
input_size=(img_height,img_width, num_channels)))
```

Since you are performing **binary classification** the last `Dense` layer will be as follows:

```
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

Also, as a bonus, the model compilation will be as follows :

```
model.compile( loss='binary_crossentropy' , optimizer='adam' , metrics=['accuracy'] )
```

Answer (score 0):

**The basic CNN sequencial model**

```
cnn_model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3,3), activation="relu",input_shape=(256, 256, 3)),

    keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3,3), activation="relu"),
    keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.25),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3,3), activation="relu"),
    keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.25),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3,3), activation="relu"),
    keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.25),

    keras.layers.Flatten(),  # neural network building
    keras.layers.Dense(units=64, activation='relu'),  # input layers
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.25),
    keras.layers.Dense(units=128, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.25),
    keras.layers.Dense(units=256, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.25),
    keras.layers.Dense(units=3, activation='sigmoid')  # output layer
])
print('Summary')
```

*Hope this helps*